# 'While True' loop does not run

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

My code:

```
def make_response(self):
    recognised = False
    get_cmd = False
    database = {
        "hello": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
        "hi": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
        "hey": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
        "goodbye": "Bye. See you next time!"
    }

    self = self.lower()

    for i in database:
        if i in self:
            recognised = True
            value = database.get(i)
            print(value)


def robot():
    print('Welcome to robot.py')
    print('What can I do for you?')

    while True:
        query = input('>')
        make_response(query)


robot()
```

When I input "hello", the program gives the intended response but it just exits without completing the loop. Which line broke the loop??
Thank you.

Comment: It works on my machine :D

Comment: I could not reproduce this. When executing on repl.it it loops.

Comment: I ran on PyCharm

Comment: Try running the code in a terminal, I have had a similar problem recently and when I changed terminals it worked.

Comment: You might not want to call the variable self ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesnt break. Please verify your solution. Here is modified code

```
database = {
        "hello": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
        "hi": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
        "hey": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
        "goodbye": "Bye. See you next time!"
    }


def make_response(self):
    self = self.lower()
    value = database.get(self, "Sorry I dont understand")
    print(value)


def robot():
    print('Welcome to robot.py')
    print('What can I do for you?')

    while True:
        query = input('>')

        if query == "goodbye":
            value = database.get(query)
            print(value)
            break
        else:
            make_response(query)

robot()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x, works fine.

Maybe you're compiling with python 2.x. In that case, you need to use 'raw_input' instead of 'input', but I don't recommend raw_input (it's deprecated in Python3).

Try Python 3.x.

PS: Also, I'd replace 'self' with other variable name. Self is used in classes.

Comment: I am using python 3.8 32-bit

Comment: It's fine for me in python 3.8 64-bit GNU/Linux (Trisquel). Ensure your compiling version. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally unable to reproduce that. It keeps prompting for new inputs, just like the code says.

As an aside, though, here's a slight simplification, using `dict.items()`:

```
database = {
    "hello": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
    "hi": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
    "hey": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
    "goodbye": "Bye. See you next time!",
}


def make_response(query):
    query = query.lower()
    for keyword, answer in database.items():
        if keyword in query:
            print(answer)
            break


def robot():
    print("Welcome to robot.py")
    print("What can I do for you?")

    while True:
        query = input(">")
        make_response(query)


robot()
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code works perfectly in my machine. But problems with Python 2.7 version. I prefer you to work with Python 3.6 or above.

Here is a simplified code.

> Code:

```
def make_response():
  database = {
        "hello": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you",
        "hi": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
        "hey": "Nice to meet you. What can I do for you?",
        "goodbye": "Bye. See you next time!"
      }
  return database

def robot():
    print('Welcome to robot.py')
    print('What can I do for you?')

    while True:
        query = str(input('>'))
        database = make_response()
        if query in list(database.keys()):
            print(database[query])

robot()
```

Check it out.
I hope it would be helpful.